# Cp + not want to overwrite permissions

Tags: linux, file-permissions

How to use cp command without to overwrite target file permissions

For example

```
cp /tmp/file /home/file
```

I dont want to change chown and chgrp on `/home/file`

Comment: Don't [cross-post](http://serverfault.com/questions/273949/cp-not-want-to-overwrite-permissions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
cp -a
```

(archiving) or

```
cp -p
```

(preserve mode, ownership and timestamps)

Comment: Isn't this exactly what is _not_ intended?

Comment: @maxelost Only if the target file exists. There's two ways to interpret the question. Copy changes permissions to the user doing the copying, and that is likely not what is intented.

Answer (score 3):

There is a better answer [at ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/273949/cp-not-want-to-overwrite-permissions):

```
cp --no-preserve=all source target
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the --no-preserve option